# convert datetime passed into parameter to a string c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, type-conversion, string-conversion

I would like to convert a datetime passed into parameter into a string using this function but it doesn't work. Could anyone help me ? Thank you in advance

Here is my function

```
public string ConvertDateTimeToString(DateTime date)
        {
            string date_str = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            return date_str;
        }
```

and after when i create a new dateTime object

```
DateTime dateTest = new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52);
ConvertDateTimeToString(dateTest);
Console.WriteLine(dateTest); /// show this {01/05/2008 08:30:52}
```

Comment: `ConvertDateTimeToString` doesn't change the type of the `dateTest` variable. `ConvertDateTimeToString` _returns_ a string.

Answer (score 1):

The "ConvertDateTimeToString" will create a new string.
The existing DateTime still untouched.

You have to use the new string in your Console.WriteLine :

```
var dateString = ConvertDateTimeToString(dateTest);
Console.WriteLine(dateString);
```

Comment: @alexeusebio: If this solved your problem, accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left ..